# Service with BatteryStateChangeBroadcastReceiver and Notification not working

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make a notification which displays some information about the battery status and refreshes itself every time the BatteryState changes.

First I registered a service in the Manifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".BatteryStatusNotification"/>
```

Then I made the Class and implemented the methods for the service. After that I wrote the NotificationBuilder and the BatteryStateChange BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class BatteryStatusNotification extends Service {

    int level;
    String pluggedString;
    String temperature;
    String voltage;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            int plugged= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, 0);

            DecimalFormat tempformatter = new DecimalFormat("##,##,#");
            int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
            temperature = tempformatter.format(temp);

            DecimalFormat volformatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
            int  vol = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, 0);
            voltage = volformatter.format(vol);

            switch (plugged) {
                case 0: pluggedString = (getResources().getString(R.string.batteryUncharging));
                    break;
                case 1: pluggedString = (getResources().getString(R.string.batteryChargingAC));
                    break;
                case 2: pluggedString = (getResources().getString(R.string.batteryChargingUSB));
                    break;
                case 4: pluggedString = (getResources().getString(R.string.batteryChargingWireless));
                    break;
            }

            batteryStatNotification();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int StartId) {
        this.registerReceiver(this.batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void batteryStatNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_battery)
                .setContentTitle(pluggedString + " | " + level + " %")
                .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.notiTemp) + " " + temperature + " | " + getResources().getString(R.string.notiVol) + " " + voltage + getResources().getString(R.string.volts))
                .setOngoing(true);


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(2, builder.build()); //Notification Id 2 = Battery
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(2);
    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I have a ToggleButton:

```
    //Toggle Battery Notification
    ToggleButton batteryToggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.batToggleNotification);
    batteryToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                prefEditor.putInt("batteryToggle", 1);
                prefEditor.commit();
                enableBatteryNotification();
            } else {
                enableBatteryNotification();
                disableBatteryNotification();
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
                prefEditor.putInt("batteryToggle", 0);
                prefEditor.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    int batteryTogglePref = sharedPref.getInt("batteryToggle", 0);

    switch (batteryTogglePref) {
        case 0: toggle.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case 1: toggle.setChecked(true);
            break;
    }
```

Which saves its own state and returns to it when the App is started and calls these two methods:

```
public void enableBatteryNotification() {
    startService = new Intent(this, BatteryStatusNotification.class);
}

public void disableBatteryNotification() {
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BatteryStatusNotification.class));
}
```

I also have an WifiNotification which is refreshed by an alarm. The WifiNotification works perfectly but my BatteryNotification doesn't.

EDIT FOR @Sreekumar R:

```
public void enableWifiNotification() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("FileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int numberSP3 = sharedPref.getInt("numberSP2", 1);
    int unitSP3 = sharedPref.getInt("unitSP2", 1);

    startService = new Intent(this, WifiNotificationService.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, startService, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * numberSP3 * unitSP3 , pendingIntent);
}
```

Can you explain why I don't need to call:

```
getBaseContext().startService(startService);
```

here?

Comment: Do you see something in logcat? Do you see if your BroadcastReceiver is listening to ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED?

Comment: @axl coder thank you for your help but Sreekumar R solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to call

```
getBaseContext().startService(startService);
```

or change the line startService = new Intent(this, BatteryStatusNotification.class); to

```
startService(new Intent(this, BatteryStatusNotification.class));
```

to start the service.

Comment: I did both and this did the trick. I edited my question for you with another little question can you explain it to me?

Comment: I still don't have comment permissions. So commenting on my own answer. The startService() is where the actual service is started and registerReceiver() is where it registers for broadcast Intents
In first case the registration is done in the onStartCommand which gets called only when the service starts.
In second case, I am assuming this is done elsewhere since you mentioned it is working